# Visual Theme for DIY.SE?

Tags: discussion, design

I've noticed that some of the other SE sites have moved away from the "default" theme that DIY is now on.  I think that as we grow, we should create our own theme as well.  Any suggestions for what this should contain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get a theme when you graduate from public beta.  We're still waiting on a huge traffic jump to get the green light.

I think the existing theme is pretty close to what I would choose.  I like how it resembles a blueprint (thanks to the graph paper background).  Just build it up a little bit so it's distinct from the beta theme, dotted lines, callouts, etc.  Definitely like the "Under Construction" feel.

Comment: we are planning a much more overtly blueprint-y design, but I totally agree

Comment: needs more caution tape!

Comment: Wait a minute, how did the spelling on 'moar' get corrected? Is there an anti-meme-type spelling filter, or does someone have super comment edit powers?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Steve said, the stats we look for prior to launch are here

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement

For context, the overall network stats are at

http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true